# Struggling with dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I would appreciate it if somebody could help me solve the following exercise.

Write a function that takes a string containing words separated by spaces and creates a dictionary where the keys correspond to the last characters of the words of the string, whilst the associated values correspond to the lists having the words ending in that character.

Furthermore, the lists must be lexicographically sorted

Example

```
string = "This will be an amazing experience"
```

Should return the following dictionary

```
{'s':['This'], 'l':['will'], 'e':['be', 'experience'], 'n':['an'], 'g':['amazing']}
```

I have an idea of how the exercise should be solved. However, given that i am still a beginner in Python, i struggle.

The first thing i did is create an empty dictionary. Secondly, I converted the string of words into a list using the **split** method. Afterwards, i created another list that takes the last character of the words of the first list of strings and puts it into the new list.

I used **dict** in order to put the elements of the second list as keys in my dictionary which works quite well. The problem is i cannot put the list of corresponding words as values.

Here is my code:

```
def dictionary (string):

    mydict = {}
    mylist = string.split()
    mylist2 = []

    for word in mylist:

        mylist2.append(word[-1])
        mydict = dict((el,(word[-1] for word[-1] in mylist)) for el in mylist2)

    return mydict
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need two lists, the algorithm is pretty simple:

1. initialise an empty dict
2. split the sentence into words
3. loop through the words
4. get the last character of the word, this is the key for the dict
5. check if that key already exists in the dict, and if not, initialise it with an empty list
6. append the word to said list

```
result = {}

for word in string.split():
    key = word[-1]

    if key not in result:
        result[key] = []

    result[key].append(word)
```

There are ways to shorten that using [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) or [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), but this is the basic idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to make a dictionary with an empty list with a default value. Then while iterating over the list of words, you can extract the last character as a key and add the word to the value list for that key

```
import collections

def dictionary(string):

    #Dictionary with default value as empty list
    mydict = collections.defaultdict(list)

    #Iterate over list of words
    for word in string.split():

        #Take last character and add word to the value list for that character
        last_char = word[-1]
        mydict[last_char].append(word)

    return dict(mydict)

print(dictionary("This will be an amazing experience"))
```

The output will be

```
{'s': ['This'], 'l': ['will'], 'e': ['be', 'experience'], 'n': ['an'], 'g': ['amazing']}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the lexicographical sorting part, you'll need to remember to sort the lists
once you've generated them:

```
my_string = "This will be an amazing experience"

def make_dict(string):
    my_dict = {}
    for word in string.split():
        my_dict.setdefault(word[-1], []).append(word)
    for l in my_dict.values():
        l.sort()
    return my_dict

print(make_dict(my_string))
```

Another possibility is to build heaps, rather than lists, and then quickly
generate sorted lists from those heaps. Depending on your exact use-case, your
mileage may vary.

Comment: This really helped me. Is there any book or website you would recommend reading to learn all this stuff? Thank you very much

Comment: Hi @alex108. You're quite welcome! I personally learned Python just by doing lots of projects and googling problems I had to find StackOverflow answers : ). Oftentimes if you have a question someone else will have asked it before - sometimes it takes a bit of searching to get it, but this will get easier as you get better at Python-speak.

Comment: I think i would really benefit by reading the whole official python documentation, what do you think?

How long did it take you to become fluent in Python? Just curious.

Comment: @alex108, I'd say a couple of months - although I don't think I'll ever stop learning new things about Python (and programming in general!). The official documentation is a great resource. I'd definitely recommend reading the expository parts of pages like the documentation for the `re` module if you find yourself using `re`, but I'm not sure how much you'll gain from just reading it all in one go - I personally always learn better by figuring out things as I need to apply them.

Answer (score 0):

```py
st = "This will be an amazing experience"
def func(st):
    d={}
    for v in st.split(' '):
        if v[-1] in d:
            d[v[-1]].append(v)
        else:
            d[v[-1]]=[v]
    return d
print(func(st))
```

Comment: Could you please add some textual information? How exactly does your code snippet help to solve the issue?